# How do I delete entries from my GitHub Activity Feed?

Tags: github

I prefer my Activity Feed to contain only project-relevant actions (e.g., commits). I recently found my feed polluted with my issue comments. How can I remove specific entries from my GitHub Activity Feed (and prevent this from happening again)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'll have to deal with it...

> From: Tekkub (GitHub Staff) Subject: [Contact] activity feed
>
> I'm afraid that's not possible currently, sorry about that.

Comment: It's a pity they don't have such support. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 10):

> From: Steve Ward (support@github.com) Subject: Public Activity
>
> We can clear your entire public activity for you, but not individual
>   events. Let me know if you'd like me to do that for you.
>
> Cheers, Steve

Comment: Nice quote, but what are you trying to tell? That it is possible now?

Comment: isn't the quote clear enough ?

Answer (score 5):

GitHub support advised me that as a matter of policy they do not clear public activity unless it exposes sensitive information.