# How long is my public activity stored?

Tags: github, rss

According to the answers to [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/20738/122501), there is no way to manually delete entries from one's GitHub activity feed. Are activity entries ever *automatically* deleted? Specifically, is there a limit to the number of activity entries that are stored and/or displayed, or perhaps a limit to the length of time any single entry is stored and/or displayed? Or is the entire history of my public GitHub activity stored forever?